# How to release memory whilst navigating web documents using a Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

The following code, run in a windows form, creates a WebBrowser control and navigates to a number of URLs. Each time a URL is navigated to the memory consumed by the application increases and never seems to get released. In my case the memory consumed rises from ~10 Mb to ~45 Mb navigating just 4 documents. I need to navigate several hundred documents which quickly causes all the physical memory to be used.

How do I release the resources used by the WebBrowser control?

```
    private void ProcessDocs()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        DateTime dtWaitUntil = DateTime.Now;
        string[] arrInputUrl = new string[] { "http://www.google.co.uk/", "http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com/", "http://www.amazon.co.uk/" };

        for (int i = 0; i < arrInputUrl.Length; i++)
        {
            using (WebBrowser objWebBrowser = new WebBrowser())
            {
                string txtInputUrl = arrInputUrl[i];
                tboxTestingOutput.Text += "\r\n" + txtInputUrl;

                objWebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                objWebBrowser.Navigate(txtInputUrl);

                //Should do this a better way, but, wait 10 secs for document to complete.
                //Would use objWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event
                //but it seems to fire several times per document load!!!
                dtWaitUntil = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);

                do
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                } while (DateTime.Now < dtWaitUntil);

                //Do whatever I need to with the document contents
                //...
                //...
            }
        }

        tboxTestingOutput.Text += "\r\nFinished";
    }
```

Comment: If you just need to read the Web pages content did you consider using `WebRequest` instead? (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)

Comment: Well, we know it consume 45MB, that's peanuts for a browser.  What we don't know is how much VM it consumes when it crashes.  Have you actually waited long enough or are you just guessing that it just keeps going up?  That's not how the memory manager works.

Comment: @MiMo I use WebBrowser to navigate to the final redirected page which may be the result of HTTP header redirects, Javascript redirects, SWF redirects, etc, many of which are not handled by WebRequest.

Comment: @Hans Passant That's a very good point. I switched to the using statement just before posting the question. Without the 'using' statement all memory was consumed. Just testing now.

Comment: After further testing @Hans Passant is correct. Memory usage peaks at ~85%. I should have used the 'using' statement from the outset.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't completely recommend it, P/Invoke SetProcessWorkingSetSize with -1 should force an empty of the process working set, for example:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr handle, int minSize, int maxSize);

SetProcessWorkingSetSize(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle,-1,-1);
```

Read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx